# Call a template file in hook_block_view

Tags: views, 7, hooks, blocks

So I'm using the `$block['content'] =` right now to display the **html** for my module. But I can't bake any php into it with it laying inline like that.

How can I make a call to my custom template file that I've added to my module directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your module use hook_theme() in **drupal 7**

```
function YOURMODULE_theme() {
  return array(
    'YOURMODULE_CUSTOM_THEME_NAME' => array(
      'variables' => array('title' => NULL, 'path' => NULL), // eg: if you want $title, $path in ur tpl. you can use any variable or an entire array/object.
      'template' => 'CUSTOM-TPL',
    ),
  );
```

and in your module folder ,create CUSTOM-TPL.tpl.php

now you can call it in

```
$block['content'] = theme('YOURMODULE_CUSTOM_THEME_NAME', array('title' => $title, 'path' => $path));
```

for **drupal 6** , user 'arguments' instead of 'variables' and

```
theme('YOURMODULE_CUSTOM_THEME_NAME', $title, $path);
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help :)

you can call your template file by using the hook system

- register your template with [hook_theme()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7)
- Call theme('nameoftheyourtheme', $args)

$args is an array that contains the arguments to the template as specified by your hook_theme() implementation.

This link might also help you, [Hook_theme and template files](http://www.nicklewis.org/drupal-hackers-cookbook/theming/hook_theme-and-template-files) (but its for D6)